# Successive ipywidgets buttons

Tags: python, button, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm trying to make a successive process of buttons clicks using ipywidgets buttons.

Click on button 1 is supposed to clear button 1 and display button 2 etc...

It looks like the introduction of the wait variable make my purge function unreachable, and I don't understand why.

```
from ipywidgets import Button
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

def purge(sender):
    print('purge')
    clear_output()
    wait=False

for i in range(5):
    print(f'Button number :{i}')
    btn = widgets.Button(description=f'Done', disabled=False,
                        button_style='success', icon='check')
    btn.on_click(purge)
    display(btn)
    wait=True
    while wait:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while wait: pass` loop is an extremely tight loop that will likely spin a CPU core at 100%. This will bog down not just your program but perhaps even your entire computer.

I think what you want to do is to display the next button not in the for loop, but in the `on_click` callback.

```py
from ipywidgets import Button
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

def purge(i):
    print(f'Button number :{i}')
    clear_output()
    btn = widgets.Button(description=f'Done', disabled=False,
                        button_style='success', icon='check')
    btn.on_click(purge, i + 1)
    display(btn)

purge(1)
```

Then you can put an `if i == 5` in your function to do something else when they reach the last button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think you solved part of the problem but the button is still blocked. The purge function is not reached. The code looks accurate in terms of logic, so I think the bug is linked to my use of the ipywidgets library.

Answer (score 0):

Although probably not the cleanest, here is my solution.

Buttons' and other ipywidgets' attributes are dynamically modifiable:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.display import clear_output

# Create and display button
button = widgets.Button(description="Begin")
output = widgets.Output()
display(button, output)

# Initialize variable
i = 0

def update_button(args):
    global i  # Declare i as a global variable
    with output:
        print("Button %s clicked." % i)
       
        # Button attributes' change conditions
        if i<2:
            button.description = 'Next'
        else:
            button.description = 'Done'
            button.button_style='success'
            button.icon='check'
        
        # Do something different on each button press
        if i == 0:
            # Do stuff
            print('Doing stuff')
        elif i == 1:
            # Do other stuff
            print('Doing other stuff')
        elif i ==2:
            # Do some other stuff
            print('Doing some other stuff and finishing')
        i=i+1
        clear_output(wait=True)

button.on_click(update_button)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

The code extends the `widgets.VBox` class.

A collection of `widgets.Button` instances are passed into the class `ButtonCascade`.

When the instance of `ButtonCascade` is initialized, an `on_click` handler is assigned to each button using the `partial` function from `functools`.

The signature of an `on_click` handler only takes one argument which is the widget instance. Using `partial` allows to "load" a function with all required arguments in a signature except for the widget instance.

```
from functools import partial

import ipywidgets as widgets

# Create a collection of buttons
# When one is clicked, it styles the previous one and then displays the next one


class ButtonCascade(widgets.VBox):
    """Display a button that when clicked changes style
    and then displays the next button in a collection of buttons."""

    def __init__(self, buttons):

        # Set on_click handlers.
        # Use partial function from functools
        # to pass the index of the button.
        for index, button in enumerate(buttons):
            button.on_click(partial(self._handler, index))

        # hide all but first button
        for button in buttons[1:]:
            button.layout.display = "none"
        self.buttons = buttons

        # Call parent. Display buttons vertically.
        super().__init__(self.buttons)

    def _handler(self, index, button):

        # If the desired result is to hide the clicked button
        # then use
        # button.layout.display = "none"

        button.button_style = "success"
        button.disabled = True
        print(f"Button index {index} clicked.")

        try:
            # Show the next button.
            self.buttons[index + 1].layout.display = "revert"
        except IndexError:
            print("No more buttons.")


# create n buttons
n = 5
buttons = [
    widgets.Button(
        description=f"button {n}", disabled=False, button_style="", icon="toggle-down"
    )
    for n in range(n)
]
display(ButtonCascade(buttons))
```

Here are screenshots of the result from clicking each successive button:

[image: first click]
[image: second click]
[image: third click]
[image: fourth click]
[image: fifth click]