# ipywidgets progress for loop when pressing Button and change Button description

Tags: python, jupyter, python-asyncio, ipywidgets

How to create a for loop that proceeds to the next item when a Button widget is pressed?
The Button description should be updated in the for loop.

In the official documentation of [Asynchronous widgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Asynchronous.html), they show how to stop a for loop and then proceed to the next item when the user moves an IntSlider widget. It is mentioned that a similar result can be achieved with a Button, even though Buttons have a different interface than other widgets.

What I want is the same desired outcome of an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62113899/successive-ipywidgets-buttons). Even though the question has an accepted answer, from the comments it is clear that the answer does not produce the desired outcome.

Comment: I answered my own question, but I am more than willing to accept a different answer, if better in any way: more pythonic, more concise...

Answer (score 3):

This code works, and it is based on the example from Asynchronous widgets documentation mentioned in the answer.

```py
import asyncio

from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets


out = widgets.Output()

def wait_for_click(btn, n_clicked=0):
    future = asyncio.Future()
    
    def on_button_clicked(btn):
        btn.description = f"Clicked {n_clicked} times!"
        future.set_result(btn.description)
    
    btn.on_click(on_button_clicked)
    
    return future


n_changes = 5

btn = widgets.Button(description="Never Clicked")


async def f():
    for i in range(n_changes):
        out.append_stdout(f'did work {i}\n')
        btn_descr = await wait_for_click(btn, n_clicked=i + 1)
        out.append_stdout(f'\nasync function continued with button description "{btn_descr}"\n')
asyncio.ensure_future(f())

display(btn, out)
```

The most important part is `wait_for_click`, a function that is called in each iteration of the for loop, and updates the Button description from "Never Clicked" to "Clicked N times!".
`wait_for_click` also returns the Button description as a string.
`wait_for_click` is a modification of `wait_for_change` from the documentation: instead of waiting for a modification of the IntSlider, it waits for a click of the Button.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a global variable that keeps track of the position, and then access your data by that position when the button is clicked, e.g.:

```py
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
output = widgets.Output()

display(button, output)

def on_button_clicked(b):
    global ix
    global button
    with output:
        ix += 1
        button.description = f"Button click {ix}"
        # do something here (e.g. process_some_data(ix))
        clear_output()
        print(f"Button clicked {ix} times")

ix = 0

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```